# UIKit Swift 5: Set UIView Rotation Angle

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an app with a compass feature with some added functionality. My goal is to rotate the compass `UIImageView` in accordance with the true north.

Is it possible to set a specific rotation angle to the image (like in Photoshop or Figma) instead of rotating it by a certain amount?

My current implementation looks like this:

```
    func rotate(view: UIView, radians: Double) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            view.transform = view.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(radians))
        }
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        let newRad = deg2rad(newHeading.trueHeading)
        rotate(view: compassImageView, radians: compassRad-newRad)
        compassRad = newRad
    }
```

I'm hoping to do something to the effect of:

```
compassImageView.layer.setRotationAngle(radians: newHeading.trueHeading)
```

Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
func rotate(view: UIView, to angle: Double) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
    }
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    let newRad = deg2rad(newHeading.trueHeading)
    rotate(view: compassImageView, to: newRad)
    compassRad = newRad
}
```

Or it might be `-newRad`, depending on which way these angles go, which I could never remember :)

Comment: Not quite! the thing is, rotated(by:) adds to the existing rotation angle of the UIImage (say if it was rotated by .pi/2 already, rotated(by: .pi/2) rotates it an extra 90 degrees. The behavior I want is to set a new rotation angle. Something like:
setRotationAngle(to: .pi/2) sets it to 90 degrees to the right of the initial rotation
setRotationAngle(to: -.pi/2) sets it to 90 degrees to the left of the initial rotation, so a 180 degree rotation to the left.

Comment: @OmarKhodr Ah oops! I just noticed that I edited the important change to your code out when I was trying to make the answer more complete in the second revision! Silly me! Now it should work.